# Passing custom CLI parameters to Inno Setup uninstaller

Tags: batch-file, installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I want to pre-configure my custom uninstall batch script with parameters passed to the `unins000.exe`.
I already achieved it for the installer, but for some reason it doesnt work for the uninstaller.

Here is the Inno Setup Script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\resources\app\Setup\install.bat"; \
    Parameters: "python-3.10.7-amd64.exe {param:pysetup|standard}"

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\resources\app\Setup\uninstall.bat"; \
    Parameters: "python-3.10.7-amd64.exe {param:ole|2} {param:defxml|2} {param:pywin|2} {param:python|2}"
```

Note: The `Run` Section works (`setup.exe /pysetuptype=...`), but the `UninstallRun` section doesn't work (`unins000.exe /ole=... /defxml=... /pywin=... /python=...`)

Here is my `uninstall.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF

:OLE
IF "%2"=="1" GOTO :UNINOLE
IF "%2"=="0" GOTO :DEFXML

SET /p answer=Do you want to uninstall oletools? Y / N 
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU Y GOTO :UNINOLE
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU N GOTO :DEFXML
ECHO [Y]es / [N]o
GOTO OLE

:UNINOLE
ECHO Y | pip uninstall oletools[full]
ECHO.

:DEFXML
IF "%3"=="1" GOTO :UNINDEF
IF "%3"=="0" GOTO :PYWIN
SET /p answer=Do you want to uninstall defusedxml? Y / N 
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU Y GOTO :UNINDEF
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU N GOTO :PYWIN
ECHO [Y]es / [N]o
GOTO DEFXML

:UNINDEF
ECHO Y | pip uninstall defusedxml
ECHO.

:PYWIN
IF "%4"=="1" GOTO :UNINPYWIN
IF "%4"=="0" GOTO :UNINPY
SET /p answer=Do you want to uninstall pywin32? Y / N 
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU Y GOTO :UNINPYWIN
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU N GOTO :UNINPY
ECHO [Y]es / [N]o
GOTO PYWIN

:UNINPYWIN
ECHO Y | pip uninstall pywin32
ECHO.

:UNINPY
IF "%5"=="1" START /WAIT %1 /uninstall /passive EXIT
IF "%5"=="0" EXIT
SET /p answer=Do you want to run the Setup for Python v.3.10.7 to uninstall Python? Y / N 
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU Y GOTO :PYSETUP
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU N EXIT
ECHO [Y]es / [N]o
GOTO UNINPY

:PYSETUP
ECHO.
ECHO python-3.10.7-amd64.exe will start now
START /WAIT %1

EXIT
```

What do I have to change for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) in the `UninstallRun` section are resolved on install time. Not on uninstall time.

If you need to use uninstall time parameters, you have code it in Pascal Script with use of [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) and [`ExpandConstant`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) support functions and [`CurUninstallStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged).

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\resources\app\Setup\install.bat"; \
    Parameters: "python-3.10.7-amd64.exe {param:pysetup|standard}"
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  Filename, Params: string;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    Filename := ExpandConstant('{app}\resources\app\Setup\uninstall.bat');
    Params := ExpandConstant('python-3.10.7-amd64.exe {param:ole|2} {param:defxml|2} {param:pywin|2} {param:python|3}');
    if not Exec(Filename, Params, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox(
        'Uninstallation failed with code ' + IntToStr(ResultCode),
        mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

---

Related question: [Inno Setup Scripted Constants in uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64636442/850848)